# Static and Dynamic Linking Sandbox

Tags: java, python, sandbox, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I was trying to use [libsandbox](http://openjudge.net/~liuyu/Project/LibSandbox) in my project.I am  able to run c/c++ program in this sandbox perfectly.
In order to run c/c++ program , firstly I have to compile the code as:

```
g++  -lm  --static  <filename>  2> err.txt
```

Then i have to run the [sample sandbox program](http://ncu.dl.sourceforge.net/project/libsandbox/0.3.5/sample2.py) with the above compiled code.

Please note the flag **--static** , that i used above is quite important.The importance of --static is reflected in following two stackoverflow answers [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10957362/1348550) , [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10863494/1348550)

Now,I want to use this sandbox  for java as well as python.
But i don't know the **gcc/g++ --static**  equivalent of  python and java.

Will the following Works?

```
  javac --static    <filename>  2> err.txt 

  python  --static  <filename>  2>err.txt
```

*I repeat , I am confused as I don't know equivalent of --static in java or python.*

*Thank you!*

Comment: Being an interpreted language, Python doesn't do any linking, static or otherwise.

Comment: And neither does Java.  All such binding is at runtime.  Can you explain what you are trying to do and why?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Sir, I had just edited my question in order to reflect the importance of --static.

Comment: @ritesh_nitw But why do you want to do this?

Comment: @peter Lawrey:The binary executable to be sandboxed is better linked statically, because loading shared libraries involves system calls, like SYS_open(), that are forbidden by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to sandbox the Python interpreter with `libsandbox`. You need to handle a few system calls for, say, loading shared libraries and importing default python modules. A working example of `pysandbox` over Python3 interpreter can be found in Richard Lobb's `CodeRunner` project,

https://github.com/trampgeek/CodeRunner

Java has its own security mechanisms. So it is unnecessary to wrap the Java VM within a sandbox.

DISCLAIMER: I am the author of `libsandbox`.

Comment: @ritesh_nitw: They are compiler flags used to turn the warnings into errors and show all the errors. You can read about it here http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: Hi, running python in a sandbox is still a problem for me.Running C/C++ is simple i just have to write 'python Sample2.py a.out' ,where a.out is the executable file.
But in python there is no executable file.When i type 'python Sample2.py python userscript.py' in command line , the sandbox doesnot work.userscript.py is the user program which i want to run in a sandbox. There is no proper document for running user python program in a sandbox. Thankyou!

Comment: @ritesh_nitw, just letting you know, there is a working example of sandboxing `python3` scripts using the policy from CodeRunner,  https://gist.github.com/liuyu81/5034438

Comment: @liuyu: Thank you for your reply. The example in above link is for 64 bit linux OS. I tried to change the code for my 32 bit machine.When i ran sandbox,:
result: BP
trace> SYSCALL
{'mem_info': (3016, 3016, 8, 8, 108, 0), 'elapsed': 2, 'cpu_info': (0, 0, 0, 0L), 'signal_info': (0, 0), 'syscall_info': (45, 0), 'exitcode': 0}

I ran the following command: <DIR>/python pytrace.py helloworld.py

Where DIR is the directory in which i have kept the sandbox pytrace.py and other required files like which.py,sandboxpolicy.py,etc and helloworld.py is the python script that i want to run in sandbox.

Comment: @ritesh_nitw, `BP` means *bad policy* -- meaning there was error in your modified version of the policy. Make sure your can successfully `import sandboxpolicy` within python's interactive console. I have pushed a few modifications to the gist repo, and `py3trace.py` now works on `i686` systems. But you still need to hack `sandboxpolicy.py`  (add appropriate system call numbers to `sc_safe['i686']`) to make the policy work on `i686` systems.

Comment: @liuyu: I downloaded the gist just from git hub and ran the command    python py3trace.py hello.py and got the following output: 
result: RF . Even if i run the simple hello world python program, the sandbox always gives "RF".

Comment: @ritesh_nitw, `RF` means some of the actions made by 32bit python3 interpreter were *restricted* by the policy. You need to hack `sandboxpolicy.py` and add necessary system calls to `sc_safe['i686']`.

Comment: @liuyu:Ok i will do it. But a simple program that just print "Hello World" in python is a safe system call, is n't it? So that should have passed the Sandbox policy.Even when i run a  blank python script, i got the same RF error.Any way i will try adding safe system call, and will see.Thank you!

Comment: @ritesh_nitw, Python scripts are not native programs. Even a "Hello World" python script would trigger a couple of system calls involving file operations (i.e. loading shared libraries, importing builtin packages, etc.); and these op's are potentially dangerous if granted without argument-level inspection. This is why the `sandboxpolicy.py` form CodeRunner took special care of system calls like `open` and `unlink`. So it has to be `RF` by default -- that is, until you figured out everything it does, and relax those restrictions explicitly within your policy.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confusing two things. Your Python program is not an executable in the sense that `libsandbox` is talking about. The executable is the Python interpreter.

So, you cannot sandbox a Python script with `libsandbox`.

You *can*, however, sandbox the Python interpreter. You do this the same way you sandbox any other executable. Either:

- Create a static build of the Python interpreter (with any C extension modules you need compiled in), and run that in the sandbox. This is not easy, but it's doable, and there's information in the Python source tree and elsewhere that may help.
- Use a more lenient sandbox that allows the standard interpreter to do everything it needs (which may including dynamically loading extension modules, depending on whether you need that) but no more.

Either way, you will need some trial and error to figure out what you can and can't disallow, and how to map different bits of Python code to syscalls, and so on. And there will be some things that you just can't prevent your script from doing, because the same syscall you don't want Python code to execute is necessary for the interpreter itself.

Effectively the same thing is true with Java. The JVM is the executable, not your program. And you really can't statically link the JVM, so you only have the second option.

Unless, of course, you're using `gcj` to compile your Java code to native code instead of JVM code. In that case, you're actually using the same backend as with `gcc` and `g++`, and you just use `--static` to make sure `libgcj` and everything else gets statically linked. You may still run into problems, because `libgcj` is doing a lot more under the covers than `libc`… but the concept is the same as with C code.

(The JVM itself has its own access model, and you could presumably build something using reflection in the classloader to sandbox Java programs at the level of the Java API instead of the linux syscall API. I don't know if such a thing already exists.)

---

> Whenever I tried to compile the program(Which i want to run in a sandbox) without "--static" , the sandbox didn't work.So, again --static is quite pivotal,, that is beyond my knowledge.

Most likely, your actual code doesn't open any files, so you're using the default sandbox settings that forbid opening files. But if you dynamically link your program, it has to open the `.so` files to link against them—which doesn't work, because your sandbox is configured to forbid it.

If you statically link the same program, the problem goes away, because it no longer needs to open any `.so`s to run. That, in a nutshell, is the point of static linking for sandboxing. You even explained this in a comment to your question, so I can't imagine how you could not understand it, unless you don't even understand why you might want to forbid `SYS_open` and what it means to do so.

> (a)For java and python, will the sandbox work if i compile w/o "--static"

Yes, the sandbox will work just fine. Which means, if you're using the default configuration, it will forbid you from opening files. Which means your Java or Python program will fail, because the VM/interpreter has to open (among other things) your program to run it.

Even linking the interpreter or the JVM statically wouldn't help that. You'd have to get the actual bytecode for your program statically linked into the executable. Not impossible, but probably well beyond anything you want to even contemplate at this point.

The right thing to do is figure out exactly what syscalls you're trying to forbid, and why, and configure the sandbox appropriately. The default configuration will not work for you.

> (b)There is a sandbox called pysandbox by the same developer openjudge.net/~liuyu/Project/LibSandbox

`pysandbox` is just an easier way to configure and start a sandbox. You don't use it from inside your sandboxed code. (There is a *different* [`pysandbox`](https://github.com/haypo/pysandbox#readme) by another developer that sandboxes your code at the Python level. That may be useful to you, but it's not the same thing as a syscall sandbox.)

---

At this point, I'm not sure you even know what you're trying to do. Why do you want to sandbox your code in the first place? Do you know what kinds of access your code needs in order to do what it needs to do? If you know what you're trying to do, are you sure a syscall-level sandbox is the right level to enforce it at, as opposed to something like [`RestrictedPython`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython)? Without knowing your actual use case, I can't even guess at the answers to these questions. But if you don't have immediate answers to all of them, you're not going to accomplish anything useful.

Comment: Let me say something before I ask a for a couple of suggestions from you.
Whenever I tried to compile the program(Which i want to run in a sandbox) without "--static" , the sandbox didn't work.So, again --static is quite pivotal,<WHY??>, that is beyond my knowledge.
I have two questions in my mind:
(a)For java and python, will the sandbox work if i compile w/o "--static"
(b)There is a sandbox called pysandbox by the same developer http://openjudge.net/~liuyu/Project/LibSandbox . So ,for running python code in a sandbox , is pysandbox much easier?
Thank You!

Comment: ... if you don't understand why you need `--static` to begin with, maybe you should figure that out first.

Comment: @kindall:Yeah, I agree. But to be honest , I already mentioned, I don't have clear cut idea about --static. I already posted the two links in stackoverflow , from where i learnt importance of it in sandbox.

Comment: @ritesh_nitw: Let me edit the post, because that's way too much to explain in comments.

Comment: The answer to your last question : I am using sandbox for my "Online Judge" security. Plenty of opensource sandbox libraries are available.I found libsandbox is quite friendly,secure and easy to use.And explicitly known for Sandboxing program ran by Online judge .

Answer (score -2):

For Java, it appear your only option is to use  JNI wrapper which is statically bound to it.  There may be such a wrapper already, but if you you can write one.

Comment: Statically bound to _what_? You don't link to `libsandbox`. The reason the OP is asking about statically linking is because you can use a simpler and cleaner sandbox when you rule out any dynamic code loading, which for C and C++ code means you have to statically link all libraries instead of shared.

Comment: @abarnert To use JNI you must provide a DLL or SO.  This can have other libraries statically bound to it.

Comment: Yes, but what would be the point of having other libraries statically bound to it? The whole reason to use static linking with sandboxed executables is so you can blacklist things like `SYS_open`. But if you do that, JNI just won't work (and neither will the JVM itself).